# How can I order Groups in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In WPF, the CollectionViewSource allows for sorting (SortDescriptions) and grouping (GroupDescriptions). However, I can't find a way to order the groups. Is it possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource animals}, Path=AnimalList}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Category"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Category" />
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Just add two SortDescriptions.Adding two sort descriptions allows us to sort the groups first and then the items within the groups.

For more check here

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=17

Comment: Despite the fact that there is no domain bea.stollnitz.com (anymore): While `GroupDescriptions` can contain any class deriving from `GroupDescription` -- having to only override method `GroupNameFromItem` which translates any input object to any output object, the `SortDescriptions` only supports the STRUCT (!!!!!) `SortDescription` which only targets property names. There is no way to correlate that 2 worlds, a struct and an abstract class.

Comment: this didn't work for me... I'm using `ICollectionView` in the code behind (not xaml)

Comment: This would effectively sort the contents of the groups, not the groups themselves. To sort the groups (by some property of "Category"), he should first sort by that property (via SortDescription, as in your answer) and then by Category (assuming Category implements IComparable; alternatively he can use some property of Category that can serve as an id).

Comment: Use `GroupDescription.CustomSort` to provide an `IComparer` for the groups.

Answer (score 6):

Groups sorting is possible though it's not so straightforward. I'll explain it on the example.

```
class CollectionElement
{
     public string Name {get; set; }
     public string Group {get; set; }
}
```

If you wish to group elements and sort the groups alphabetically then sort elements within each group alphabetically then you should do the following:

1. Add [PropertyGroupDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.propertygroupdescription.aspx) referencing `Group` property
2. Add [SortDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription.aspx) referencing `Group`
3. Add SortDescription referencing `Name`

The grouping process seems to work effectively like the following way: Iterate through **already sorted** elements consequently. When encountering element form unknown group - create a group and add it to groups list. When encountering element from existing group - add it to the existing group. (Actual implementation may be different). So if your elements are sorted in the order you wish your groups to appear you will effectively sort the groups.

Comment: Some code would be nice! Still struggling with this.