# WPF ListCollectionView custom grouping/sorting by List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf

**My Setup**

I'm using `ListCollectionView` to sort and group my data in `ListBox`.

My model:

```
public class Game
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public List<string> Categories
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

What I want do to is to group by `Categories`, where groups in view are sorted alphabetically. And also sort all items in groups by `Name`.

Also I want to have group representing null or empty Categories at bottom of view.

For example:

```
Category1
    Name2
    Name3
Category2
    Name2
    Name3
    Name4
    Name5
Null/Empty
    Name1
    Name6
```

Since `Categories` is `List<string>` it means that any item can be in one or more groups or none.

**Problem**

I don't know how to properly implement sorting for categories. I know that I have to set multiple `SortDescriptions` to sort by `Categories` first and by `Name` second, but how do I do that?

WPF doesn't known how to sort `List<string>` groups by default so I tried to change it to custom List which implements `IComparable`, but that can't handle null values (comparer cannot be called if one of the objects is null).

I also tried to implement `CustomSort` on my view, but I thinks it's not impossible to handle my situation that way (where one item can be in multiple groups).

**Update full repro code**

The result is:

```
Null
    Game1
Category2
    Game2
    Game3
Category1
    Game3
    Game4
```

And I want it to be:

```
Category1
    Game3
    Game4
Category2
    Game2
    Game3
Null
    Game1
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Game
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public List<string> Categories
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var games = new List<Game>()
        {
            new Game()
            {
                Name = "Game1",
            },
            new Game()
            {
                Name = "Game2",
                Categories = new List<string>() { "Category2" }                    
            },
            new Game()
            {
                Name = "Game3",
                Categories = new List<string>() { "Category1", "Category2" }
            },
            new Game()
            {
                Name = "Game4",
                Categories = new List<string>() { "Category1" }
            }
        };

        var view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(games);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Categories"));
        MainList.ItemsSource = view;
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="grouping.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:grouping"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="MainList">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander Header="{Binding Name, TargetNullValue='Null'}" IsExpanded="True">
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I order Groups in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747130/how-can-i-order-groups-in-wpf)

Comment: That possible duplicate doesn't handle grouping by Lists, which is the main problem in my situation.

Comment: You should use a different type in your WPF application if you want to be able to use the built-in grouping functionality. Each Game should have a Category string property that defines which category it belongs to. It shouldn't have a List<string> property.

Comment: So you want same item to appears in different groups? The easier is to create new list, where you have duplicated items with `Name`, but different `Group` (and group should be a `string`).

Comment: @mm8 But in my situation any Game can have multiple or none categories set, that's just real use case that I need to support. Also WPF properly creates groups when grouping by List<string> so it is somehow supported, but the main problem is to properly sort them.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal repo of your issue including sample data and XAML.

Comment: @mm8 I've added full example code showing what the problem is.

Comment: Each property that you sort by must implement IComparable. List<T> does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your data are not in suitable format for displaying in WPF. You want the same entry to appear in multiple places (once per group), while the typical itemssource will display each item once, no matter the sort details.

So you should translate your data to a representation that is more natural to WPF. For example (with custom comparer for sorting):

```
public class GameListEntry : IComparable<GameListEntry>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(GameListEntry other)
    {
        if (Category == other.Category)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (Category == "Null / Empty")
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (other.Category == "Null / Empty")
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return Category.CompareTo(other.Category);
    }
}


List<Game> games = ...;

var listedGameEntries = games.SelectMany(x => x.Categories.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(c => new GameListEntry { Name = x.Name, Category = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ? "Null / Empty" : c }));

var groupedGames = listedGameEntries.GroupBy(x => x.Category);
```

The CompareTo might need to be enhanced or replaced by a different mechanism in order to make the sorting and grouping work the way it should.

Edit: added `DefaultIfEmpty()` in order to ensure one entry even with an empty list of categories.

Comment: I was afraid that I will have to do that. Right now I store everything in single `ObservableCollection<Game>` list, which updates view nicely when something changes in the collection. Changing data representation to what you propose will complicate things a lot, but I guess it's might be the best solution :(

Comment: @JosefNemec Your `Categories` is not an observable collection, so if the categories of an existing game would change, the view would have no reason to update... I don't agree with the *"updates view nicely"* ;)

Comment: In real application it is `ObservableCollection`, I just didn't include it in example scenario.

Comment: @JosefNemec note my edit, might be important for the `"Game1"` entry of your sample data.