# How to sort groups in a ListView using a custom sort?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, sorting, listview

I have a `ListView` filled with items, and these items are collected in groups.
I can sort the items in each group (for example alphabetically) - this is simple by using the `CustomSort` property.

But the problem is to sort the groups themselves by different custom sort depending on their headers texts.

How can I do this? 
for example take the following picture

[image: Show this image]
I sorted the files by name but groups not sorted the same way. how can I control the order of groups themselves.

Comment: Can you provide an example? What is the DataSource of the listview?

Comment: I updated the question and added a photo for illustration.

Comment: Take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747130/how-can-i-order-groups-in-wpf).