# WPF GROUPED Datagrid: how to sort groups themselves by vm property?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, grouping

Scenario: a datagrid to show custom events from custom sources.
The grid must group rows by source, ordering events by datetime descending (newer always on top). No manual sorting allowed, virtualization enabled, MVVM pattern.
Here's my issue: the group header itself must follow the datetime ordering, that is the group containg the latest event must scale to top.

ViewModel:

```
public class Event
{
   public Int32 Source_Id { get; set; }
   public String Source_Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime Event_DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

CollectionView is grouped by Source_Id and sorted by Event_DateTime:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key='alarms_src' Source="{Binding Alarms}">                
   <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Source_Id" />
   </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
   <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
      <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Event_DateTime" Direction="Descending" />
   </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

GroupStyle is a simple expander with source name and latest event datetime into the header:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="LightGray">
                                <Expander.Header>

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">

                                        <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="{Binding Items[0].Source_Name}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="{Binding Items[0].Event_DateTime}"/>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>

                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander.Content>

                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>                
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Output:
[simplified grid](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3413cc1f60c6f2f59c9383f74a53ccc820181128120743/e56e01)

The red arrows in the image points to the 4th row I've generated, with the latest timestamp.
The grid is correctly grouping and sorting INSIDE each group, but what I expect is that the Device_1 group would scale on top of the grid: how to obtain this?

Update: [wetransfer link to sample project](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3413cc1f60c6f2f59c9383f74a53ccc820181128120743/e56e01)

Comment: This is a similar question with answer: [How can I order Groups in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747130/how-can-i-order-groups-in-wpf)

Comment: GroupDescriptor has a [CustomSort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.groupdescription.customsort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_GroupDescription_CustomSort) property. Maybe take advantage of it?

Comment: @Fabio Could you provide your GroupStyle Xaml and if you have used any converter for the Xaml paste that code too, it will help

Comment: @SatishPai: requested code added

Comment: @Fabio , Since you mentioned "but what I expect is that the Device_1 group would scale on top of the grid: how to obtain this?" i missed that you were mentioning about timestamp, will get back to you on this.

Comment: @Fabio added a new answer, I guess this will answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(testdg.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Here testdg is my DataGrid Control name.

What i thought is to refresh the itemsource of the datagrid and the rest sorting will be taken care. Checkout the method.

```
    private void addEvent(Int32 source)
    {
        Event a = new Event();
        a.Source_Id = source;
        a.Source_Name = "Device_" + source.ToString();
        a.Event_DateTime = DateTime.Now;

        this.Alarms.Add(a);
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(testdg.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

Sorry, misunderstood your question previously.

Comment: @Fabio Did this solution work for you ? I was waiting for long time.